# extjs 4.2 FiltersFeaturenot working with filtered store

Tags: extjs4.1

I am new to Extjs,I filtered the store and I am passing that to grid.Inside grid I am using FiltersFeature,but the filter showing the actual store instead of filtered store i.e showing all the values instead of filtered values.
   How can I handle this.Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Filters Feature does not read the actual settings of filters in store. You can workaround that by not filtering the store but call filtering functions of the filters instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Could you give me sample code please, as I want filtered the data and apply filters on that filtered data.
My requirement is I have side bar having two buttons based on the click Event I was filtering the data in the store.

Comment: I do not use Filters Features personally, I use [MultiSearch Plugin](http://extjs.eu/software/ext-grid-multisearch-plugin/), nevertheless, you need to call [addFilter](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.filters.Filters-method-addFilter) (and other filtering functions) of the **Filters fature**, not the store directly.

Comment: Thanks,I removed filters in store and resolved that issue.Now I am facing new issue.It is the grid filters are not updating though I am reloading the store,as and when I click on filters first time the same values are coming across irrespective of store data.How can I refresh/reload the grid filters as and when I load the store?

Comment: you should accept this answer and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I removed filters in store and resolved that issue.